# Navbar width not scaling to 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, vue-component

I'm creating a website for my project. And i want to be responsive. But my navbar no not scale.
I've tried `width: 100%;` etc.. but it doesn't work. code for it is [Here](https://github.com/Bialu-Software/Website/blob/main/src/components/GumerTest.vue). I'm using Bootstrap v5.1.3 for it.

[image: The problem]

Comment: `display: block` ?

Comment: Please go read [mre]. Do not just dump code on external platforms (where it could change, or disappear from, at any time, making this question mostly worthless to future readers) - it needs to be included directly inside your question; in text form & properly formatted, or as a Stack Snippet in cases where that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Does `<div id="app">` have a fixed width? It may be stopping the navbar to expand to 100% of the viewport.

You could try:

```
.nav {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

or

```
.nav {
  min-width: 100vw;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Now i have answer. It was posts. They aren't responsive so navbar was stuck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).